# Проблемы с выводом БД Sqlite в список с системным simple_list_item_2

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Необходимо из БД вывести на экран список в формате `simple_list_item_2`. В этом системном `layout` есть два `textview`. Приложение с использованием данного `layout` вылетает. Однако при использовании собственного `layout`, который содержит один `textview`, приложение запускается и всё выводит, но уже конечно не в том формате как надо. Я так понимаю, что необходимо как-то прописать, что из получившегося из БД `ArrayList`'а одно поле соответствует 1му `textview`, а другое поле 2му textview из `simple_list_item_2`. Видел примеры с переопределением, но там используется класс, а у меня БД. Подскажите пожалуйста, как решаются подобные проблемы.

```
public class IdevOwnSqliteDbActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "yourdb.sqlite3";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "friends";
    private static final String FRIEND_ID = "_id";
    private static final String FRIEND_NAME = "name";
    private static final String FRIEND_POEM = "poem";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> friends;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();

        fillFreinds();
        setUpList();
    }

    private void setUpList() {

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, friends));
                //R.layout.my_list, friends));
        listView = getListView();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position,long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            ((TextView) view).getText() +
                             " could be iDev's friend",
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void fillFreinds() {
        friends = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor friendCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,
                                             new String[] 
                                             {FRIEND_ID, FRIEND_NAME, FRIEND_POEM},
                                             null, null, null, null
                                             , FRIEND_NAME);
        friendCursor.moveToFirst();
        if(!friendCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                String name = friendCursor.getString(1);
                String poem = friendCursor.getString(2);

                friends.add(name);
                friends.add(poem);

            } while (friendCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        friendCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что ArrayAdapter не будет работать со вторым `textview`, попробуйте реализовать таким образом.

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// если вы используете ListActivity не нужно прикреплять макет.

ListView listView = getListView();

ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();

try {
        db = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query("friends", new String[] {"_id", "name", "poem"}, null, null, null, null, null);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                 cursor, new String[]{"name", "poem"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}); 

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "База данных недоступна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View itemView, int position, long id) { 
      Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "position == " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Не понял) Ни откуда и что такое context, list, getName() и getAge() . Понятно, что я должен это привести к своему коду, но т.к. осваивать начал только-только, то очевидные вещи для меня не всегда очевидны. Прошу не судить строго.

Comment: вот к примеру у Климова в первом примере [ссылка](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/simpleadapter.php) то, что надо, но как это привязатьк моему случаю с БД - не пойму.

Comment: Обновил код, сейчас вроде более внятно

Comment: Вы в самом начале открываете БД, затем делаете запрос к таблицам, затем создаете `simpleCursorAdater` и в него передаете данные из ДБ, далее, в методе `onListItemClick` реализовываете то, что будет происходить по нажатию на любой из пунктов

Comment: Отлично! Всё заработало! Конструкцию SimpleCursorAdapter надо было мне правильно оформлять. Спасибо!